# An error was reported when attempting to reference the mongocxx header file in the header file

Tags: mongo-cxx-driver

When I try to reference mongocxx's header files in header files, the compilation reports an error, but there is no error when referencing these header files in cpp. The error is as follows:"usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/types.hp:41: Parse error at "/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi/bsoncxx/enums/type.hpp""

How do I properly reference these header files in the header files?